# Randomized Quick sort

Tags: algorithm, quicksort

In randomized Quicksort, should I randomize the input data first and then use the first element as the pivot, or should I not change the input data but choose a random pivot?

I am a bit confused about what needs to be randomized.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your array is not randomly distributed already, then just select a random pivot on the array, that is what randomised quicksort is for.

If your array is previously randomised, then use a normal quicksort

Answer (score -1):

An easy way to do this is:

Simply take the array input as it is. Choose a random index in the array everytime, and replace it with the last element. And then take the last element as the pivot, as you would in a normal quick sort.

Hope it helps.